# Check WCF for a very large json string

Tags: json, wcf

I need to send more than 20000 articles in a synchronization process, this process is sent by a WCF in JSON format. But serializing the list of articles tells me that the string is too big for the process.

I have tried in the following ways:

Increase in my REGEDIT the values ​​"MaxFieldLength" and "MaxRequestBytes" in the following path 
"Computer \ HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Services \ HTTP \ Parameters"

Add the following tags in my webconfig

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize = "2147483647" maxBufferSize = "2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize = "2147483647" messageEncoding = "Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth = "2000000" maxStringContentLength = "2147483647" maxArrayLength = "2147483647" maxBytesPerRead = "2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount = "2147483647" />
    </ binding>
  </ basicHttpBinding>
</ bindings>
```

Also, try generating the Service class with scvutil urlServicio / Service1.svc

and I use the following properties:

```
    EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress("urlServicio/Service1.svc");
        BasicHttpBinding binding = CreateBasicHttp();
Service1Client cliente = new Service1Client(binding, endPoint);
private static BasicHttpBinding CreateBasicHttp()
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding
            {
                Name = "BasicHttpBinding_IService1",
                MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = long.MaxValue
            };
            TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 120);
            binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
            binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;

            return binding;
        }
```

But he does not read me the binding or the endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into an upper limit pertaining to the data contract serailizer. Check if this applies to you.

```
<system.runtime.serialization>
    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="100000" />
</system.runtime.serialization>
```

Another set of limits and some you did not mention above are the limits you may be hitting in the web server (IIS). The configuration above and the configuration you posted pertain to WCF and .NET serialization. The article below shows the caps made by the web server.

[Limits you can set in the System.Webserver config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/).

Another thing you have missed from above is the [MaxBufferPoolSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxbufferpoolsize(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: The sentence you gave me, made in my project, is to give a longer search time but I still present the same error

Comment: Check the link I posted and make sure your requests are not violating a web server policy.

Comment: Already verify the page that you indicate me and my IIS is well configured, I am presented with the following error:

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element. ---> System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededException: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Comment: this is my client's app.config

`<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" 
                 maxBufferPoolSize="52428800"
                 maxBufferSize="65536000" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>`

Comment: `<client>
      <endpoint address="http://192.168.0.181/wcfPrueba/Service1.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>`

Comment: It seems the only valiue you have not set is the MaxBufferPoolSize. I added a link above.

Comment: Can solve my problem by generating a Service class, with svcutil.exe. There do not configure anything and I work despite the size